# linux tc htb bandwidth ceil being ignored and giving improper results

Tags: linux, traffic, traffic-shaping, tc, htb

I'm setting up some htb packet queues like so:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 10: htb
tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 10: htb

tc class add dev eth0 parent 10: classid 10:1012 htb rate 750kbps ceil 750kbps
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 handle 1: cgroup
tc class add dev eth1 parent 10: classid 10:1012 htb rate 750kbps ceil 750kbps
tc filter add dev eth1 parent 10: protocol ip prio 10 handle 1: cgroup
```

And am testing it by downloading a 10MB file using wget.
I have verified that the packets have the correct classid on them.

When I do the download without these tc rules, I get an average download speed of ~ 9MB/s

When I apply the limit, my speed drops, but it drops to the wrong number.  It tops off consistently at 3.7MB/s.

I have no idea why my limit is going over by so much especially considering I have a ceil set.  I did notice that the download appears to start limited at 750kbps, but then starts incrementily gaining speed.

Any one have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have an [IMQ](http://linuximq.net/)? Otherwise, this won't work. ["With linux only egress shaping is possible (except for the ingress queue which can only do rate limiting). IMQ enables you to use egress qdiscs for real ingress shaping."](https://github.com/imq/linuximq/wiki/WhatIs)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ahh, no I don't have that, and yes I was expecting to be able to ingress shape....thanks for the helpful info/link.  Although I'm somewhat confused as to why setting these filters is lowering the download speed from 9MB to 3MB

Comment: Throttling the outbound is slowing the inbound. You need an IMQ to sensibly rate limit inbound traffic.

Comment: You should say how eth0 and eth1 are connected and how you have defined your cgroup so we can understand your tc rules.

Comment: @IanMacintosh David^ already answered this without posting an actual answer.  I didn't delete the question since there is some useful info here.

Answer (score 2):

Without further knowledge on your actual config I am going to assume you have a cgroup problem.

Try this to exclude your cgroups and just to limit the device itself.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Using ifb device to shape ingress traffic
modprobe ifb
ifconfig ifb0 up

# flush tc
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root &> /dev/null
tc qdisc del dev eth0 ingress &> /dev/null
tc qdisc del dev ifb0 root &> /dev/null

# limit all outbound traffic
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit

# forward inbound traffic to ifb
tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0

# limit all inbound traffic via ifb egress
tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev ifb0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit
```

Test and you should see that it works both inbound and outbound. If you only want to limit in one direction, just ignore the other part.

Comment: Rooster, just noticed your comment above after I posted my answer. Let me know if this doesn't clear it up for you or if it's otherwise not useful and I'll just delete.